# Put signs between digits so that the number results in 100

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, numbers

I need help with the problem below.Given a number , I have to put signs(+,-, * ,/) between the digits to check if any combination results in 100.We can group digits into groups of more than one , but we cannot change the order of the digits.For example 593347 → 5 + ((9 / (3 / 34)) – 7) = 100,271353→2-(7*(((1/3)-5)*3)=100, while 707409 never results in 100.I can understand that dynamic programming is the solution, however I can't find the exact algorithm.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to find all such solutions, or just assert the existence (or not) of some solution?

Comment: No, I just need to check if any combination results in 100.That means that if we find it in our first try we stop the algorithm,differently we have to check all possible combinations.

Comment: how large a number can be?

Comment: in that case, why not use brute force?? Try putting every operator in every possible location and evaluate. Or is brute force not acceptable??

Comment: (  ) is allowed?  depends on what language you used, without something like eval(),  evaluate the expression during brute force may be hard. I will go for brute force as well, as the complexity is not that bad for n <= 10: ~O(2^n * n)

Comment: brute force is allowed as well as parenthesis.I ll be writing this in C.How can I  evaluate the expression in C?

Answer (score 2):

Let's simplify for a moment. Imagine the number is 1234.

Step 0: Is the number 100? no

Step 1: Look at 1 and 234.

- Step 1a: Can we find an answer for 1 + f(234)? This requires that we
  invoke our function with number 234, and answer 99 (because 1 + n =
  100 implies n = 99).
- Step 1b: How about 1 - f(234)? This requires
  that we invoke our function with number 234, and answer -99 (because
  1 - n = 100 implies n = -99).
- Step 1c: How about 1 * f(234)? etc.

Step 2: Look at 12 and 34.

- Step 2a: Can we find an answer for f(12) + f(34)?
- Step 2b: Can we find an answer for f(12) - f(34)?
- etc.

Each time you invoke the function with a specific number and an expected result, store the answer so you can use it again if it gets invoked with those same arguments.

That's a sketch of the dynamic programming solution to this problem.

I suspect it would take massive amounts of computing time and memory to do this. It's hard enough when the problem is constrained to + and -. See https://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2013/12/07/algorithm-plus-minus-result-100/ for example.

Comment: For the case 1+f(234, 99) it is trivial, because we know the second call must result in 99. But in the case f(12, ?)+f(34, ?), which values are we looking for?

Comment: Yes @JuanLopes, that's a complication. The results influence each other. So perhaps f(12) returns a set `v` of values that can be generated, and f(34,`v`) looks for 100 - each value in `v`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider looking up [Heap's algorithm for permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm). Try finding a permutation where the statement equals 100

EDIT: Thanks to Gassa 
it's both: permutation for the order of operations and Cartesian product for the operations themselves.

Comment: As there may be multiple similar signs, the combinatorial object in question is cartesian product, not permutation.

Comment: Upd: actually, it's both: permutation for the order of operations and Cartesian product for the operations themselves.

Comment: ahh that's what I was missing

Comment: Could you please provide me with an algorithm in pseudo-language because I don't get it exactly?Thanks

Comment: @algozer If there are always six digits, you can go straightforward, like: for (permutation denoting the order of operations) for (op1) for (op2) ... for (op5) {evaluate the resulting expression}.